# Mongoose: value from Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following model:

```
var requestSchema = new Schema({
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  country: { type: String, index: true },
  shipping: [shipping],
  deliveryLoc: { type: String, index: true },
  price: { type: Number, default: 0 },
})
```

I now want to get the price using mongoose and I am not sure which command I have to use.

I tried:

```
var pricy = _.first(_.where(request.price));
```

and it does not work, I get undefined even through through other queries in the same file I can get "shipping".

Getting the shipping type works with the following command:

```
var shipping = _.first(_.where(request.shipping, { type: shippingType }));
```

Am I using the wrong command?

Comment: `price` isn't an array, so why aren't you just accessing its value directly as `request.price`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the select method as follows:

```
// find a request 
var query = Request.findOne();

// selecting the `price` field
query.select('price');

// execute the query at a later time
query.exec(function (err, request) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The price is $%s.', person.price) // The price is $6.92
});
```

or if passing a callback:

```
var Request = mongoose.model('Request', requestSchema);

// find each request with a country matching 'Zimbabwe', selecting the `price` field
Request.findOne({ 'country': 'Zimbabwe' }, 'price', function (err, request) {
     if (err) return handleError(err);
     console.log('The price is $%s.', request.price) // The price is $6.92.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. These methods don t work for what I am trying to do now, unfortunately. I am searching more for something like :             var shipping = _.first(_.where(request.shipping, { type: shippingType }));

. This is giving me the shipping type back but somehow it does not work on the price...

Comment: How do you get the Mongoose object `request` then?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create your schema like that:

```
var items = new Schema({
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  country: { type: String, index: true },
  shipping: [shipping],
  deliveryLoc: { type: String, index: true },
  price: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});
```

After that you need to compile the new schema and add it to the database:

```
items = mongoose.model("Items", items); // The table name will be "Items"
```

When the model is created, you can execute your query (find or findOne):

```
items.findOne({price: request.price}, function (error, item) {
  if (error) {
     console.log(error);
  } else {
     console.log(item);
  }
});
```

The full code:

```
var mongoose, Schema;

mongoose = require("mongoose");
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var items = new Schema({
   description: { type: String, required: true },
   country: { type: String, index: true },
   shipping: [shipping],
   deliveryLoc: { type: String, index: true },
   price: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

items = mongoose.model("Items", items);

items.findOne({price: request.price}, function (error, item) {
   if (error) {
      console.log(error);
   } else {
      console.log(item);
   }
});
```